# Llvm for custom SOCs

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, soc

I am looking to write an llvm backend for a custom SOC. The problem is that it has some non-standard instructions to dma data, cache operations etc.

Apart from using intrinsics, is there any other approach to developing a toolchain backend for custom SOCs. In general, I am open to other methods that can give me a high-level representation of the program and can convert it to SOC instructions.

Answer (score 1):

If it's just a number of extra instructions on top of some already supported ISA, intrinsics is what you should use, by design. Alternatively, an inline assembly if your assembler supports the instructions you want.

If the entire ISA is new, the most common approach to building a new LLVM backend is still to start off one of the existing backends which is sufficiently close to yours, and gradually modify it. Writing a new one from scratch will require a lot of boilerplate to be produced before you'll even start implementing your first instruction.

Comment: Sadly, not. It is completely new as in the opcodes, registers are new. On _top_ of that, there are special instructions which don't have any counterparts on other ISAs.

Comment: @abjoshi, then you'll be better off starting by cloning some *similar* or *generic* ISA. Usually people take MIPS as a base, unless you've got something highly unusual (e.g., a VLIW), then something else might be a good start. You can also follow a sequence of commits for the RISC-V target to see how you can evolve a new backend from scratch.